# Inner Join mysql in single table

Tags: php, mysql

I have created table where on date there will be 3 status entered, Solved, Unsolved and OnHold. I have created following query from this I want to create bar chart which should show 3 bars of status date wise.

```
select a.date, a.Solved,b.Unsolved, c.OnHold 
from (select count(prob_stat) as Solved, date from delivery 
where prob_stat='Solved' group by date) a 
inner join (select count(prob_stat) as Unsolved, date from delivery 
where prob_stat='Unsolved' group by date) b on a.date=b.date 
inner join (select count(prob_stat) as OnHold, date from delivery 
where prob_stat='OnHold' group by date) c on a.date=c.date
```

but it doesn't work, I can see only 1 record as a result. Can anybody help?

Pravin

Comment: Sample date and the expected output would be needed to really help

Comment: I am looking for output as below:
Date            | Solved | Unsolved | OnHold
2016-02-20 |  1         |     2           |   0
2016-02-21 |   2        |     1           |    1

Comment: I am looking for output like this
Date          |  Solved  | Unsolved  | OnHold
2016-2-15 |   2          |    1            |   1
2016-2-16 |    2         |    1            |   0

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select `date`,
sum(case prob_stat when 'Solved' then 1 end) as Solved,
sum(case prob_stat when 'Unsolved' then 1 end) as Unsolved,
sum(case prob_stat when 'OnHold' then 1 end) as OnHold
from delivery
group by `date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like...
That working fine

```
SELECT 
  date,
  COUNT(CASE prob_stat WHEN 'Solved' THEN 1 END ) AS Solved, 
  COUNT(CASE prob_stat WHEN 'Unsolved' THEN 1 END) as Unsolved,
  COUNT(CASE prob_stat WHEN 'OnH' THEN 1 END) AS OnHold 
FROM delivery 
GROUP BY date;
```